# Gradle - How to publish sub-projects from root project

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have a hierarchical gradle 2.16 project like this

```
Root
|- subProject1
|- subProject2
|- subProject3
```

`subProject2` has dependency to `subProject1` & `subProject3`. `subProject3` has dependency to `subProject1`.

Gradle publish project in order. First it publish `subProject1`, than `subProject2` and than `subProject3`. but I need to this, first `subProject1` should be publish than `subProject3` and finally `subProject2`.

Now I want to publish `subProject2` from `root` project so that if `subProject1` & `subProject3` are not published they get published in local repo. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will make the dependent sub project to build and publish first and than build the required subproject. Add this to parent `build.gradle` file.

```
project(':subProject2') {
    compileJava.dependsOn(":subProject1:build")
    compileJava.dependsOn(":subProject1:publish")
    compileJava.dependsOn(":subProject3:build")
    compileJava.dependsOn(":subProject4:publish")
}
```